# How can I change a Heroku enterprise team name?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have a [Heroku enterprise team](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/enterprise-teams) with a couple of [private spaces](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces) within it. These spaces contain around 20 deployed apps. Some apps use [AWS VPC peering](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-space-peering) to non-Heroku hosted external apps. The apps use [addon's](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) such as [papertrail](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail).

Is it possible to change the team name without impacting or affecting any of these apps?

We are not actually running in Production yet, so an outage of a few hours over a weekend while we do this would be acceptable.

I can't see anyway to change the team name on the UI or CLI, so I am guessing that I may have to resort to creating a new team and [transferring apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/transferring-apps) to that team. Is that the way to go? If so, will it likely be seamless or can I expect a world of pain?

We only want to change the name because we have renamed our product/project, we could probably live with the old name if necessary.

Comment: I would actually recommend just asking their support, especially for enterprise customers (but also non-enterprise) they are always quite helpful and fast.